# Android 12 TV Box can't play Youtube Video

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube, tvbox

I am currently using Kotlin to write android TV APP, but I found that I have an APP that can successfully play Youtube videos using YouTubePlayerView on ANDROID10, but the green screen will flicker on ANDROID12. The same error occurred when I switched to using webView with built-in Youtube, and the same error happened when I switched to another brand of ANDROID12 TV box. How can I fix the problem?